# call bash script with array of strings with spaces as argument

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am fairly new to bash.
I want to call a script located on a remote linux machine, passing some normal arguments and one array. The array contains string elements which may have spaces.

I wrote a minimal example:

on the server side: copyFiles.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

msg=$1  
msg2=$2
shift           
shift
arr=("$@") # Rebuild the array with rest of arguments
for ((i = 0; i < ${#arr[@]}; i++))
do
    echo $msg $msg2 "${arr[$i]}"
done
```

On the host side:

```
first="first"
second="second"
array=("arra y1" "array2" "array3")

plink -ssh username@hostname -pw mypwd -batch  " bash scripts/copyFiles.sh $first $second "${array[@]}" "
```

Output:

```
first second arra
first second y1
first second array2
first second array3
```

What I want:

```
first second arra y1
first second array2
first second array3
```

Thanks

Comment: looks like you want " bash scripts/copyFiles.sh" "$first" "$second" "${array[@]}"

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use `\"` for space separated arguments.
Did you try to escape string with spaces in the following way:

> "\"arra y1\""

I think it may solve your issue.